Nginx 1.26: can HTTP3 coexist with HTTP2?
Nginx 1.26.0 on Debian Bookworm. It's serving HTTP3 fine as confirmed in the network protocol column in the dev tools tab in 3 different browsers. But it only serves HTTP3 if I turn off HTTP2. If I add http2 on; to any vhost, then HTTP3 is not served in any of my browsers - everything gets served as HTTP2.
The relevant part of the config for each of my three vhosts' server {} settings is this:
     # http3 (on by default)
     listen 443 quic;
     listen [::]:443 quic;
     add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';

     http2 on;
     listen 443 ssl;
     listen [::]:443 ssl;

The Alt-Svc header is being successfully added to all the served resources. But it seems I have to turn HTTP2 off in order to get HTTP3 to work? Is that correct? I would like HTTP2 to be the fallback if HTTP3 fails to negotiate or cannot be accepted for any reason, e.g. middlebox blocking, old UAs etc. Is that possible, or must I accept 1.1 as the fallback if HTTP3 cannot be served for any reason?

How did you test this? i.e. why do you think that its nginx choosing NOT to use HTTP/3.

I've got nginx adding the debug header add_header X-protocol $server_protocol always;. It's hard to get any browser to go to HTTP3 reliably though. Mostly they show only HTTP2 which is reflected in the debug header. What's weird though is that https://http3check.net always shows both sites sending HTTP3 reliably, and shows my debug header as  x-protocol: HTTP/3.0. So maybe my browers are failing to consistently negotiate HTTP3 despite emptying the cache and reloading frequently. It all feels a bit bleeding edge right now as I can't get repeatable results.

For anyone googling their way here, my site is now serving http3 with http2 as the default first response as expected. I ended up with these settings in the server block for my test vhost:
 http2 on;
 listen 443 ssl;
 listen [::]:443 ssl;

 http3 on;
 listen 443 quic reuseport;
 listen [::]:443 quic reuseport;
 add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';

I believe the ordering doesn't matter. Note you can only use reuseport once per IP:port combo, i.e. you can't use it with other vhosts unless they have different IP addresses or ports.
I think my problem was not fully emptying my test browsers' caches between swapping over nginx between http2, then http3, then back again several times in succession. In addition, Safari (my default browser) retains the Alt-Svc info in Settings/Privacy/[Manage Website Data]/{site name} as "Cache, Cookies and HTTP Alternative Services" which you may have to delete manually if reverting nginx to http2 only, otherwise it seems you can get a weird mix of both protocols. Once I let nginx settle down to http3 and properly cleared all the test browser caches followed by a full content reload, it all worked as expected.
